# DLLImport works in VS but not in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, dll

We have Soap Webservice project which uses third-party DLL. In Visual Studio, when I run the program, it works perfectly. It can find the dll. But when I put the project into IIS, webservice cannot find the dll. here is the DLLImport part below.

```
[DllImport(@"/dll/y1d431_mit.dll",
        EntryPoint = "Y1DPackG", SetLastError = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern void Y1DPackG(ref int ErrorNumb, ref int ErrorMsgs,
        string RegCustomer, int RegPassword, int CostOptim, int IgnoreLast,
        int EffortLev, int ReduceLays, int PrefShort, int DiffStocks,
        int DiffPieces, int ReusLength, int GapItIt, int GapItEnd,
        int GapGripEnd, int OptimTime, int IterMult, int LayByMark,
        int RunMsgMode, int ReservInp2, ref int StockGrLth, ref int StockGrCst,
        ref short StockGrQty, ref int PartGrLth, ref int PartGrMrkID, ref short PartGrQty,
        ref int Critsum, ref int Effsum, ref int StockSum, ref int PartSum,
        ref int LengthSum, ref int WasteSum, ref int CostSum, ref int LastStockNo,
        ref int LastParts, ref int LastLength, ref int LastWaste, ref int LastCost,
        ref int PatternSum, ref int LayoutSum, ref int LayoutCuts, ref int ReservOut1,
        ref int ReservOut2, ref short StockGrNo, ref short PartGrNo, ref short PartStockNo,
        ref short StockLayNo, ref short StockPatNo, ref short StockParts, ref int StockWaste);
```

where does the IIS look for the dll file according to the DLLImport statement? where should I put the dll files according to the DLLIMPORT statement in order for IIS to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load up Sysinternal's free [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).  Start it up right before you run the code that executes the dllimport and stop the event gathering after it errors out. This tool will tell you every single thing that is going on, including where IIS starts searching for it. Also it will tell you if you are getting permissions errors.

Permissions errors become likely if it is a 32-bit dll on a 64-bit system because the dll will then be running through WOW64 and likely copied into the WOW64 directory for execution. By default, this isn't a directory that any of the anonymous internet user accounts have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mark. Process Monitor showed me exactly where Windows was looking for my DLLImport unmanaged/native DLL, and all it's dependents/imports. I found 2 methods to have my DLL found:

Method #1: SetDllDirectory()

```
using System.Web;

public myClass
{
    private static bool dllIsLoaded = false;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    public void myDllLoader()
    {
        if (!dllIsLoaded)
        {
#if DEBUG
            string dllDir = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"Lib\Debug\");
#else
            string dllDir = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"Lib\Release\");
#endif
            SetDllDirectory(dllDir);
             // Call any function in your DLL to load it.  Stays loaded for the duration of the app.
            string ver = myDllGetVersion();
            SetDllDirectory("");    // Reset path to original

            dllIsLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Method #2: Pre-pend the PATH environment variable with my App's directory of DLL's:

```
using System.Web;

string dllDir = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"myAppDLLDirectory\");
string currentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", $"{dllDir};{currentPath}");
```

This modification of PATH affects the current process only.

p.s. If your error message says it can't find your DLL, but your DLL is on the DLL search path, it could really mean one of the DLL's your DLL is importing can't be found.  For example, my DLL depended on "vcruntime140d.dll" and "ucrtbased.dll", which I had on my development machine, but were not on the server I was deploying to. List dependencies using "dumpbin.exe /imports my.dll".  Dumpbin is available from the Visual Studio "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt".